# random generation of fixed range of numbers in array with no duplcate rows in that 2d array

Tags: c++, random

Hi i am working on the problem of generating random numbers with no duplicate rows in the 2d array.

I approached in this way i used random shuffle to do that and code is

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main ( void )
    {
        srand ( time(NULL) );
        int nsize = 4;
        int seq[nsize];
        int i;

        /* Initialize seq to an ordered range */
        for ( i = 0; i <nsize; i++ )
        {
            seq[i] = i+1;
        }
        cout<<"ele in initial array:";
        for(int j=0;j<nsize;j++)
            cout<<seq[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        int **array = new int *[nsize * 5];
        for(int i=0;i<nsize*5;i++)
            array[i] = new int[nsize];

        /* Random shuffle */
        int k;

        for(k=0;k<20;k++)
        {
            //srand ( time(NULL) );
            for ( i = nsize-1; i >0; i-- ) {
                //srand ( time(NULL) );
                int r = ( rand() % (nsize - 1 ));
                //srand ( time(NULL) );
                int save = seq[i];
                seq[i] = seq[r];
                seq[r] = save;
            }

            for ( i = 0; i < nsize; i++ )
            {
                array[k][i] = seq[i];
            }


            for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<nsize;j++)
                {
                    cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            } 
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

but the problem is it is generating same rows 
ex:

```
    2 4 3 1
    1 4 3 2 
    1 3 2 4 
    2 4 3 1 
    2 1 4 3
```

is there any better way to do that to eliminate the duplicate rows and generate unique rows in 2d array.
Thank you all for your help

Comment: You need a checksum of some kind for each row. With such small numbers, you may as well start with a large random number and break it in four pieces.

Comment: @clwhisk It looks like he's just shuffling the range `1-4`, so I don't think a checksum will help him.

Comment: Only 24 different possibilities, eh? Generate all of them, put in a list and then pick-and-remove-from-list. You only need a single 8-byte space to store each series anyway.

Comment: See this talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Is this problem about random numbers? Or about permutations?

Comment: .. I meant to say 8 *bits*, for each complete series. A list of all possibilities would be 24 bytes -- shorter than the code to generate it.

Comment: random numbers only not permutations for my problem i need unique rows in the 2d array i just given the example of 4 but the size can increase but i am just trying for 1-4 at present

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need all possible permutation of 1-4 in 24 rows, you need a way to keep track of your previous row with some temporary matrix

An easy way would be this:-

```
size_t k=0;
std::sort(arr, arr+nsize);
do {
    for(int i=0;i<nsize;i++)
     array[k][i] = arr[i];
     k++;
} while(std::next_permutation(arr, arr+nsize));
```

See [HERE](http://ideone.com/48FK5Y)

Comment: The indentation of `k++` is misleading. Also, std::copy rather than a loop would be clearer.

Comment: sorry in this example i have given 1-4 and 24 rows but my problem will increase up to 1-100 but the number of rows i need to change every time

Answer (score 0):

Track the rows you create.  When you create a new row, check that you have not already created that row.  If you have, scrap it and create the new row again.

Comment: its my small part of problem if i increase 1-20 and number of rows 4000 ? then is there any other way to do that

Answer (score 0):

This answer is like P0W's except using `std::vector` instead of arrays and afterward all the permutations are shuffled to randomize their order afterward.

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>

    int main ()
    {
        std::srand(std::time(NULL));
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > rows;
        unsigned min_value = 1;
        unsigned max_value = 4;
        rows.push_back(std::vector<int>(max_value - min_value + 1));
        for(unsigned i = min_value; i <= max_value; i++)
            rows[0][i - min_value] = i;
        while(std::next_permutation(rows.rbegin()->begin(),
                                    rows.rbegin()->end()))
            rows.push_back(*rows.rbegin());
        rows.push_back(*rows.rbegin());
        std::random_shuffle(rows.begin(), rows.end());

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++)
        {
            std::copy(rows[i].begin(), rows[i].end(),
                      std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
```